# How to search for a JSON field in elasticsearch using java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This is `JSON` that I want to use for a search:

```
{   
    "_index" : "test",   "_type" : "insert",   "_id" : "3",  
    "_version" : 2,   "found" : true,   
    "_source" : {
         "ACCOUNT_ID" : "123",
         "CONTACT_ID" : "ABC"   
    } 
}
```

How do I search for all the `JSON` which have `ACCOUNT_ID` starting from 1?

Comment: Please, clear it if, you mean : prefix of ACCOUNT_ID = 1 or ACCOUNT_ID from 1, 2, 3, ..... ?

Comment: @AbdullaAlSun The question says the Account id value is different in different JSONs(separate docs).

Comment: ACCOUNT_ID is a String value. So right now in the example it is "123", i wanna know how retrieve all the JSONs with the ACCOUNT_ID starting with "1". or

Answer (score 2):

You can use Wildcard in elasticsearch to search for an ACCOUNT_ID which starts from 1

```
GET index/_search
 {
      "query": {
        "wildcard": {
          "ACCOUNT_ID ": {
            "value": "1*"
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

In Java, you can try something like this:

```
QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("ACCOUNT_ID ", "1*");
```

Comment: QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("ACCOUNT_ID ", "1*") is giving zero hits. i mean the hits:[ ] is empty

Comment: Can you upload your Java Program?

Answer (score 1):

From what i see in your comments you are trying to find id's starting with 1 for example. Well if your analyzer is the standard one the id "123" is tokenized like "123". You can use wildcard and search like '1*'. Be careful using wildcards cause it takes some memory.

See here: [QueryString - Wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards)